# Subgroup $\{(1),(12)\}$ in $S_3$ is not kernel of any homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

How do I prove the following statement

> Subgroup $\{(1),(12)\}$ in $S_3$ is not kernel of any homomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(1\,2\,3)^{-1}\circ (1\,2)\circ (1\,2\,3)=(1\,3)$ is not in this subgroup, hence it is not normal.

Comment: Kernel of homomorphism is closed under conjugation. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that a subgroup of $G$ is normal if and only if it is the kernel of some homomorphism $G\to H$. Indeed, any kernel of $f\colon G\to H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and any normal subgroup $K\subset G$ is the kernel of the quotient map $G\to G/K$.

Since the subgroup you have described is not normal, it can't be the kernel of any homomorphism.